# filling numpy array by index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function which gives me the index for a given value. Eg,

```
def F(value):
   index = do_something(value)
   return index
```

I want to use this index to fill a huge numpy array by 1s. Lets call array `features`

```
l = [1,4,2,3,7,5,3,6,.....]
```

NOTE: `features.shape[0] = len(l)`

```
for i in range(features.shape[0]):
    idx = F(l[i])
    features[i, idx] = 1
```

Is there a pythonic way to perform this (as the loop takes a lot of time if the array is huge)?

Answer (score 2):

If you can vectorize `F(value)` you could write something like

```
indices = np.arange(features.shape[0])
feature_indices = F(l)

features.flat[indices, feature_indices] = 1
```

Comment: F(value) is not vectorized

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
i = np.arange(features.shape[0]) # rows
j = np.vectorize(F)(np.array(l)) # columns
features[i,j] = 1
```